# phx-update="append" resulting on empty container collections in DOM

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I try to follow the temporary_assigns guide line via the docs https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/dom-patching.html

I've setup the temporary_assigns on mount

```
    {:ok,
     assign(socket,
       chats: [%{id: 1, message: "hey"}],
       temporary_assigns: [chats: []]
     )}
```

and set the id for the container and child

```
    <main
      id="chat-messages"
      phx-update="append"
      class="bg-blue-100 w-full h-[640px] p-3 flex flex-col gap-2"
    >
      <section :for={chat <- @chats}>
        <div
          id={"chat-#{chat.id}"}
          class="w-full max-w-xs p-4 text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400"
        >
          <div class=" text-sm font-normal">
            <div class="text-sm font-normal">
              <%= chat.message %>
              <%= chat.id %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

But still, the container is empty and child is never showed up, but strangely when I use the phx-update="stream" instead of phx-update="append", it works, I don't why the phx-update="append" is still don't work on me, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is on the mount and the direct child element of container that should have an id so we should specify the correct contract on temporary assigns like so

```
    {:ok,
     assign(socket,
       chats: [%{id: 1, message: "hey"}]
     ),
    temporary_assigns: [chats: []]}
```

and after that the direct child of the container should have and id like so

```
<main
      id="chat-messages"
      phx-update="append"
      class="bg-blue-100 w-full h-[640px] p-3 flex flex-col gap-2">
      <section id={"chat-#{chat.id}"} :for={chat <- @chats}>
       ....
      </section>
    </main>
```